# Zooming in QGIS stops at particular scale

Tags: qgis, zoom

I seem to have a problem with the zooming levels in QGIS 2.6 Brighton. When I go to zoom in to a vector or raster layer, e.g. for digitizing purposes, the scale seems to be fixed at 1:2,256, I can't zoom in any further than this scale. My previous version of QGIS, 2.2.0 did not have this problem.

Is there a fix for this?